# Why does `map` hide a `StopIteration`?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I found a case when `map()` usage isn't equivalent to a list comprehension. It happens when `next` used as the first argument.

For example:

```py
l1 = [1, 2]
l2 = ['hello', 'world']
iterators = [iter(l1), iter(l2)]

# list comprehension
values1 = [next(it) for it in iterators]
# values1 = [1, "hello"]
values2 = [next(it) for it in iterators]
# values2 = [2, "world"]
values3 = [next(it) for it in iterators]
# raise StopIteration
```

```py
l1 = [1, 2]
l2 = ['hello', 'world']
iterators = [iter(l1), iter(l2)]

# map
values1 = list(map(next, iterators))
# values1 = [1, "hello"]
values2 = list(map(next, iterators))
# values2 = [2, "world"]
values3 = list(map(next, iterators))
# values3 = []
# doesn't raise StopIteration
```

Any other exceptions occur as they should.
Example:

```py
def divide_by_zero(value: int):
    return value // 0

l = [1, 2, 3]
values = list(map(divide_by_zero, l))
# raises ZeroDivisionError as expected
values = [divide_by_zero(value) for value in l]
# raises ZeroDivisionError as expected, too
```

It seems very strange. It works the same with Python 3.9 and Python 3.11.

It seems like `map()` works like this:

```py
def map(func, iterator):
    try:
        while True:
            item = next(iterator)
            yield func(item)
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

but I expected it to work like this:

```py
def map(func, iterator):
    while True:
        try:
            item = next(iterator)
        except StopIteration:
            break
        yield func(item)
```

Is it a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try calling `next` on `map`:

```
>>> >>> m = map(next, iterators)
>>> next(m)
1
>>> next(m)
'hello'
>>> next(m)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

It's `list` that sees `StopIteration` and uses it to stop building the list from what `map` yields.

The list comprehension, on the other hand, is building the list by iterating over `iterators`, not a particular iterator in *that* list. That is, `next(it)` is used to produce a *value* for the list, not to determine if we've reached the end of `iterators`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've found one of the rare cases where allowing `StopIteration` to bubble up like an exception causes the wrong behaviour. It's not a bug, it's just an unfortunate consequence of Python's design decision to use an exception to signal the end of an iterator; it's a pitfall, like [mutable default arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/12299000), except it shows up much less frequently.

As @chepner's answer notes, the problem is that `list` is catching the `StopIteration` and therefore thinking the `map` is exhausted, when what's actually happened is that the callback function `next` raised an exception which you want to treat like a real exception, i.e. a failure condition.

To avoid this, generally speaking you should not allow `next` to be called in a context where the `StopIteration` can bubble up and be caught in the wrong place. If you want to pass `next` as a callback, I suggest writing a wrapper around `next` which converts the `StopIteration` into an exception which won't be misinterpreted as the end of some other iterator:

```py
def safe_next(it):
    try:
        return next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        raise ValueError('Unexpected end of iterator')
```

Usage example:

```py
>>> l1 = [1, 2]
>>> l2 = ['hello', 'world']
>>> iterators = [iter(l1), iter(l2)]
>>> list(map(safe_next, iterators))
[1, 'hello']
>>> list(map(safe_next, iterators))
[2, 'world']
>>> list(map(safe_next, iterators))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in safe_next
StopIteration

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in safe_next
ValueError: Unexpected end of iterator
```

That said, in this use-case you should probably just use `zip`:

```py
>>> pairs = zip(l1, l2)
>>> next(pairs)
(1, 'hello')
>>> next(pairs)
(2, 'world')
>>> next(pairs)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```